# A lookup table / map with conditionals as keys?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, factory, software-design, open-closed-principle

I find myself often wanting to lookup something – often a function or constructor – based on a set of conditions. Is there a concise way of doing this in JavaScript? Even if there is a more concise way, is there a better approach when I find myself reaching for this pattern?

This is simple when we just need to compare against strings or numbers:

```js
const getAnimal = type => {
  const lookup = {
    'cat': Cat,
    'dog': Dog,
  }
  return new lookup[type](); // e.g. type = 'cat'
}
```

... but when I need more complex logic, the lookup keys would need to be functions. For example:

```js
const animalFactory = traits => {
  const lookup = [
    // format: [condition, Animal]
    // condition: returns true / false
    // Animal: constructor
    [likesWarmBeds, Cat],
    [isIndifferent, Dog],
  ];

  for (let [hasTraits, Animal] of lookup) {
    if (hasTraits(criteria)) {
      return Animal;
    }
  }
}

const getAnimal = (traits) => {
  const Animal = animalFactory(traits);
  return new Animal(traits);
}
```

Compared to the *lookup* in the simpler example, the *condition* values have essentially replaced string keys, and the *Animal* constructors are still the values.

I'm trying to follow the [open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). In the example above, getAnimal() could support new animals by simply adding another item to the lookup, and this wouldn't require any changes to the function itself.

Comment: I added a new example of lookups with simple strings as keys, and then changed the old isTie() code to more closely match the simpler lookup, so that no longer exists. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Have you thought about using [a Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: Yes vlaz, that's but that doesn't really help, because the conditional keys must be invoked. Map would work when you have non-string values you need to lookup (e.g. a function reference) – then you can just map.get(value) – but that doesn't work in this case.